# Reactjs keep Material Ui Tab selected on refresh

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

Hi I'm using React Material UI Tab and I noticed that on refresh the website doesn't keep the tab selected. How can I prevent this from happening? This is a code-type of material ui tab

```
class SimpleTabs extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0,
  }

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value })
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    const { value } = this.state

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <Tab label="Item One" />
            <Tab label="Item Two" />
            <Tab label="Item Three" />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        {value === 0 && <TabContainer>Item One</TabContainer>}
        {value === 1 && <TabContainer>Item Two</TabContainer>}
        {value === 2 && <TabContainer>Item Three</TabContainer>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because on page refresh the component is reinitialized, the `state.value` is set to 0.

The `onChange` method needs to store the selected tab somewhere, in the page URL for example.

In the component constructor or on `componentDidMount` the `state.value` needs to be set from the storage where it was set previously.

Answer (score 4):

I manage to solve this by using the useLocation hook and returning the state value based on the path.

```
const currentTab = () => {
    let path = location.pathname;
    if (path === "/") return 0;
    else if (path === "/path2") return 1;
    else if (path === "/path3") return 2;
    else if (path === "/path4") return 3;
    else if (path === "/path5") return 4;
};
```

and then replacing the useState value from 0 (the first tab) to the currentTab function.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(currentTab);
```

This solution helped me a lot, saw it somewhere else, so I hope it helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

This simple solution worked for me. grabing url from the browser using `window.location.pathname` and updating value state whenever browser is refreshed and reloaded using `componentDidmount` lifecycle method.

```
    class SimpleTabs extends React.Component {
      state = {
        value: 0,
      }
    
      handleChange = (event, `enter code here`value) => {
        this.setState({ value })
      }

     componentDidMount() {
     // assuming Item one as url "/" Item two as url "/itemTwo" and so on
      switch (window.location.pathname) {
      case "/":
        this.setState({ value:0 })
        break;
      case "/itemTwo":
       this.setState({ value:1 })
        break;
      case "/itemThree":
        this.setState({ value:2 })
        break;
   
      default:
        this.setState({ value })
        break;
     }
    }
    
      render() {
        const { classes } = this.props
        const { value } = this.state
    
        return (
          <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <Tabs value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <Tab label="Item One" />
                <Tab label="Item Two" />
                <Tab label="Item Three" />
              </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
            {value === 0 && <TabContainer>Item One</TabContainer>}
            {value === 1 && <TabContainer>Item Two</TabContainer>}
            {value === 2 && <TabContainer>Item Three</TabContainer>}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set value to your tab, that should do the work

```
<Tab value={0} label="Item One" />
<Tab value={1} label="Item Two" />
<Tab value={2} label="Item Three" />
```